# How to route multiple prefixes to the same route in istio?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

How to route multiple prefixes to the same route in istio ?

For example:
prefix: /api
prefix: /something_else

how to route both of the above prefixes to the same route in istio ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can get better answers to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

From the Istio official [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/virtual-service/):

> HTTP requests with path starting with /wpcatalog/ or
>   /consumercatalog/ will be rewritten to /newcatalog and sent to pods
>   with label “version: v2”.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: reviews-route
spec:
  hosts:
  - reviews.prod.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/wpcatalog"
    - uri:
        prefix: "/consumercatalog"
    rewrite:
      uri: "/newcatalog"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: reviews.prod.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v2
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: reviews.prod.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v1
```